# Waveform Transfer for Tektronix DPO3000 Scope

Tags: vb.net, transfer, waveform, oscilloscope

I'm trying to retrieve data from a DPO3034 scope by sending these these commands:

```
DATA:SOURCE CH1
DATA:ENCDG ASC
DATA:START
CURVE?
```

I get `98, 98, 98, 97, 97, 98, 98,...`
How can I convert these ASCII formatted values to voltages?

I also tried retrieving data that are binary formatted

```
DATA:SOURCE CH1
DATA:ENCDG RIBINARY
DATA:START
CURVE?
```

I get `#520000a b a b b a b c b c a b a a a b ^ b b a b a b....`
How can I convert these to proper data points?

[Command reference for the DPO3000](http://assets.tequipment.net/assets/1/26/Documents/Tektronix/dpo3000_programmermanual.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

These values you are reading using `CURVE?` are digital value that has gain and offset for turning them into (usually) volts.
You should read also these values:

```
double YZero = double.Parse(io.Query("WFMO:YZE?"));
double YMult = double.Parse(io.Query("WFMO:YMU?"));
double YOff = double.Parse(io.Query("WFMO:YOF?"));
```

And then you should calculate the real voltage from each value `rawValue` in the array you get from `CURVE?`:

```
double voltValue = YZero - YOff * YMult + (YMult * double.Parse(rawValue));
```

same goes for binary data, just parse it into int16 (depending on the bit-length of each number)

P.S.
I believe your manual is not the latest, I'm recommending downloading these from Tektonix website.